# Webpack 4 : Logs

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

While building the code with webpack, I acme across the logs like mentioned below

```
[../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 504 KiB {main} [built]
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 82:13-14
    harmony import specifier lodash [./selectors/buyInsuranceSelectors.js] 49:42-43
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 84:7-8
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 86:6-7
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 88:6-7
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 97:27-28
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 99:16-17
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 129:19-20
    harmony import specifier lodash [./client.js] 164:29-30
    harmony side effect evaluation lodash [./store/configureStore.js] 5:0-23
    harmony import specifier lodash [./store/configureStore.js] 12:23-24
    harmony import specifier lodash [./store/configureStore.js] 51:14-15
    harmony side effect evaluation lodash [./selectors/userInfoSelector.js] 8:0-23
    harmony import specifier lodash [./selectors/userInfoSelector.js] 10:25-26
    harmony import specifier lodash [./selectors/userInfoSelector.js] 12:9-10
    harmony side effect evaluation lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 8:0-23
    harmony import specifier lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 363:27-28
    harmony import specifier lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 440:15-16
    harmony import specifier lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 452:15-16
    harmony import specifier lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 460:15-16
```

Is there any way to remove these logs for example
"harmony side effect evaluation lodash [./services/GTMUtil.js] 8:0-23"
as they are too many and the terminal output becomes too crowded?

Answer (score 6):

To remove those logs, you can add a stats object to your webpack config. In that object you have to set the modules property to false.

So it would be something like this in your webpack.config.js

```
stats: { 
  modules: false
}
```

Once you do that these will be removed. If you'd like more info webpack goes over all the stats that you can toggle here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/